Upgrade to openAPI not compiling
We are doing a major upgrade from jave 8 to java 21 so we are having to upgrade many things all at once.
I am getting this crazy compiler error, I am running mvn compile and getting this error message.
[ERROR] /C:/dev/workspaces/.../src/main/java/com/.../config/SwaggerConfig.java:[13,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class builder
[ERROR]   location: class org.springdoc.core.models.GroupedOpenApi

import org.springdoc.core.models.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi  api() {
        GroupedOpenApi api =  new GroupedOpenApi.builder()
          .pathsToMatch("/path/**")   
                .build()
          ;                                           
    }

}

I have these dependencies in my pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


if you look inside of GroupedOpenApi you will see that builder() is a static method:
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}

as well as the constructor is private:
private GroupedOpenApi(Builder builder) {
   ...
}

Therefore simply remove the keyword new for it to work:
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi api() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .pathsToMatch("/path/**")
                .build();
}


oh %$£!"^%$&£%&$"%$£! I have been staring at that for HOW long...

The Docket I was replacing needed the new

It seems you're trying to describe your documentation on the basis of the OpenApi Specification.
I guess you can use this maven-starter, but did you maybe thought about using the openapi tool directly?
Maybe something like this could help you.
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <configuration>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Of course you would also need a separate YAML file to describe your specification.
Hope this could maybe help you!

it was a stupid as J Asgarov pointed out
